# opencv face recognition LBPH issue

Tags: opencv, rust, face-recognition, ffi, dlib

I have been struggling for two day to find an appropriate way of initializing PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer in rust using opencv.

```rust
let mut void_pointer = libc::malloc(mem::size_of::<c_void>() as libc::size_t) as *mut c_void;
if void_pointer.is_null() {
    panic!("failed to allocate memory");
}

let mut model = PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer::from_raw(void_pointer);
let ptr = PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer::init(model);
let mut model = PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer::deref_mut(ptr);
model.train(&images,&labels);
```

result is panic with invalid memory reference.

any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I think [`let mut model = LBPHFaceRecognizer::create(configs).unwrap();`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.53.0/opencv/face/prelude/trait.LBPHFaceRecognizer.html#method.create) is likely the intended way to do this.

Comment: @eggyal, I only realized that after I started to put together an answer. I should have used `PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer::create` since it was the only implementer listed in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `create` method. The default parameters used in C++ to initialize it are also described in the [docs](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.53.0/opencv/face/prelude/trait.LBPHFaceRecognizer.html#c-default-parameters).

```rust
use opencv::face::prelude::*;

// According to docs, these values are the defaults used in C++
let mut model: PtrOfLBPHFaceRecognizer = <dyn LBPHFaceRecognizer>::create(1, 8, 8, 8, DBL_MAX).unwrap();
```

Comment: I guess the type annotation is superfluous?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this works: see for example [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0079d1ec850369655a1379e9f23beff6).  You can do `<dyn LBPHFaceRecognizer>::create` but I'm not convinced that's how the library's supposed to be used either...  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @eggyal looks like you're right. It seems very strange that they chose to implement it for `dyn LBPHFaceRecognizer`, but I suppose it was a side effect of trying to make a stable interface to a C library.  I completely missed that during my read through of the docs.

Comment: it is so weird to use the interface like this but it works, I tried it. maybe a merge request for the create to wrap around the default value would be good. thank you for assist  @Locke